# Calculating the state space in expectiminimax (board game)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I've implemented an expectiminimax algorithm in a board game and I'm not sure how I can calculate the state space for the search tree.

It is a 2-player turn based game, where each player has 7 pieces and most go through a board that have 14 squares. Before each turn the player most roll a dice that have 5 different possibilities( a number from 0 to 4).

I know that it can be hard to calculate the state space/complexity, but is there a way to estimate that?